# ( WSO2 AM 4.1 : Token Endpoint ) Can we use the gateway as the default token Endpoint?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

in new wso2 apim versions (4.0/4.1) the default token endpoint has changed . It used to be the Gateway : https://gw.wso2.com/oauth2/token and the the call is redirected to the key manager node . Now with the news versions , we do not need to go trough that process as we can directly call the key-manager for token operations .

is there a way to preseve the same behavior of the old versions in the new version 4.1 ?

For now, I tried adding the *TokenAPI*.xml api in the synapse-configs to see if i can produce the same experience , but the api is automatically destroyed in startup.

Any ideas ?

Thank you in advance .

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the gateway removes those files.

To keep custom runtime artifacts deployed in the Gateway, add the following configuration in the /repository/conf/deployment.toml file.

```
[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway.skip_list]
apis = ["token_api_file_name.xml"]
```

Refer - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/deploying-wso2-api-m-in-a-distributed-setup/#configure-the-gateway-nodes

Comment: Hello Pubci, 

Works like a charm =) 
Thank you for your help !

Best regards