# {"code":"404","type":"Status report","message":"Not Found","description":"The requested resource is not available."}

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

we have configured latest WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0 and brought up the service, however we are seeing an error while hitting the token url

> curl https://testapi-am.example.com:8243/token
> {"code":"404","type":"Status report","message":"Not
> Found","description":"The requested resource is not available."}

tried with geting access token using 8243 port am not getting response from wso2 am 4.1.0 version,

> curl https://testapi-am.example.com:8243/token
> {"code":"404","type":"Status report","message":"Not
> Found","description":"The requested resource is not available."}

This was working on the prior version i.e wso2 API Manager 3.1.0.

On the wso2 API Manager 3.1.0 version we are not facing any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The token endpoint is no longer available in the GW, instead, you can directly call the Key Manager endpoint to generate a new token.

```
https://KM_HOST:9443/oauth2/token
```

If you want to preserve the old behaviour take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72026337/2627018) question.

Comment: for https://KM_HOST:9443/oauth2/token i'm getting the response. when going for the admin UI page wso2 APIs are accessible only through the API gateway not from the UI.

Comment: @CKR your question is not clear. Can you elaborate?